# Azure PowerShell - Send Message to VM

Tags: azure, powershell, virtual-machine, azure-automation

I'm creating some scripts in Azure Automation Accounts using PowerShell and I am wanting to send a popup to users on an Azure VM. If possible, it would be a popup that sends a response back to the script.

For further details: I'm writing a script to check the VM for a tag which holds the working hours of the user, then shuts the VM down two hours after their end time (easy enough). But just in case the user is working late / has been called out, I want to send a message for them to save their work. If the popup can send a response to PowerShell, then I'd a like a popup saying "OK" or "Delay by 1 hour". In either case the script will proceed after five minutes in case they don't respond. The script will run hourly, so no need to do more than "Continue" if the response is delay.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Hi @Axtral, did the suggested solution work for you? Do let me know if it solved your problem else share more details so I can troubleshoot or else do accept it for helping other community members.

Answer (score 2):

•   You can create an interactive toast notification for your purpose when the evening time of logging off and shutting down systems is reached. To find templates of such **interactive toast notifications and configure them**, kindly refer to the below documentation link. Also, you can send the toast **notification to the remote computers to be run as a powershell script by configuring it with the help of task scheduler** at a specific point of time.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/design/shell/tiles-and-notifications/adaptive-interactive-toasts?tabs=builder-syntax

The above link helps you in `designing the toast notification and its content like message, image, notification alignment, etc. You can also use the below github link’s ‘Toast_Notify.ps1’ powershell script to modify and configure the required notification` to be sent on the remote computers: -

https://github.com/byteben/Toast/blob/master/Toast_Notify.ps1

•   Also, find the below sample of the toast notification created using the above script itself in which you must **modify the ‘XML’ content in the script to get the desired toast notification**.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <ToastContent>
  <ToastTitle>We want to bring to your attention some important information. Please review the details below before contacting the Service Desk</ToastTitle>
   <Signature>Sent on behalf of the ICT Service Desk</Signature>
  <EventTitle>Major IT Issues - Flooding</EventTitle>
   <EventText>We are currently experiencing problems with all our systems. We are drinking coffee with our feet up and will provide an update shortly. Thank you for your patience</EventText>
    <ButtonTitle>Details</ButtonTitle>
    <ButtonAction>https://byteben.com</ButtonAction>
    </ToastContent>
```

Toast Notification image: -

[image: Toast notification image]

**Powershell command script to execute the above script**: -

```
 PowerShell.exe -File “Toast_Notify.ps1” -XMLOtherSource \\MyFileServer\Toast Notifications Custom Message\CustomMessage.xml ‘
```

For detailed information on the above, kindly refer to the below link: -

https://byteben.com/bb/deploy-service-announcement-toast-notifications-in-windows-10-with-memcm/